# Transformation rule for partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I can't fathom the step I have highlighted in green. Am I using the chain rule in 3 dimensions? What is it that I am transforming here?

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are using the chain rule. In cylindrical coordinates $r=r(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. So, as $r$ only has a dependance on $x$ and $y$:

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}$$

Comment: Does $\theta$ only have x,y dependence as tan$\theta=y/x$?

Comment: Yes, in cylindrical coordinates you have the following relations: $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}; \quad \theta=\arctan(\frac{y}{x}); \quad z=z$